# Как сделать автоответчик-меню бот для WhatsApp?

Tags: бот, navigationbar, whatsapp

Стоит задача реализовать бот-автоответчит для WhatsApp. Примерный функционал как на chat2desk.com. Посмотрел приложение для Android "Автоответчик для WA" это не совсем то. Посмотрел несколько наработок на Payton пока не нашел нужный.
Примерный функционал такой должен быть
Должно появится меню
Select your topic: send menu item number.
Выберите тему обращения: пришлите номер пункта меню.
1 - Support/Техподдержка
2 - Sales/Продажи
3 - Accounting/Бухгалт.
4 - Other info/Доп. инфо

Клиент вводит число. Переходит в следующее меню или выдается какая то информаци. 
Как это реализовать есть ли какой то сервис. C помощью чего реализовать это меню-бота.

Comment: Какой язык программирования или не важно?

Comment: Не важно. С нуля буду разбираться

Comment: тогда ищите библиотеки/sdk для работы с WhatsApp, а раз язык не важен, то и выбор у вас будет большим

Comment: Не могли бы Вы дать что то стоющее

Comment: Например: https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup или https://github.com/danielcardeenas/whatsapp-framework

Comment: Спасибо буду разбираться